# How can I extract the rate of my pandas timeseries data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-cleaning

Consider for example,

```
                    Temp       Hum        WS
DateTime                                         
2019-08-01 00:00:00   35.9615  20.51460  1.287225
2019-08-01 00:20:00   36.5795  21.92870  2.213225
2019-08-01 00:40:00   36.2885  22.62970  2.331175
2019-08-01 01:00:00   36.1095  22.76075  2.532800
```

The interval is clearly 20 minutes but is there a function to extract it?
I am writing a script to resample to lower resolution using df.resample(rate).mean()
I want to ensure that we run the script only when rate is larger than the rate of the df. It does not make sense to convert lower resolution data to a higher resolution. In this example, rate of '60T' will be acceptable because it will convert the 20 minute data to hourly data. But, a rate of '10T' should not be acceptable.

Comment: If you know the rate will be fixed and there will never be any deviations, e.g. 1 ms, you can just take the difference between two consecutive dates

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this looks like a natural way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
# if index not datetime object, then
# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
>>> pd.Series(df.index).diff().mean().components.minutes
20
#or,
>>> pd.Series(df.index).diff().iloc[-1].components.minutes
20
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends of data, if frequency is specified use [`DatetimeIndex.freqstr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freqstr.html):

```
print (df.index.freqstr)
20T
```

If not specified is possible compare it by converterted DatetimeIndex with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
idx = df.asfreq('20T').index
m = (df.index == idx).all()
print (m)
True

print (idx.freqstr)
20T
```